# How can I power MKR1000 and 25 NeoPixels 24hrs or longer?

Tags: wifi, battery, neopixel

I have an arduino MKR1000 which I would like to run off battery power for a few days with 1-3 dimly lit NeoPixels active. Every day for an hour there will be 10 NeoPixels active. Brightness for both set to 15. I'm having 2 issues. The NeoPixels start to morph into another color after an hour or thereabouts, and the MKR seems to lose track of time, as the Leds don't turn on and off on the right hour. I have also noticed that if I have the usb and battery both plugged into the MKR, the serial monitor stops working. What should I do?

Comment: What size and type of battery?

Comment: Neopixels need 5V which you won't have if you are using the lipo battery input.

Comment: It's a LiPo battery 3.7V and 2000mAh

Comment: I have followed Adafruits guide for these NeoPixels, and they write that a LiPo is ok for smaller strips of LEDs, is this incorrect?

Comment: Yes, you can feed the neopixel with 3.3~3.7V... just be sure that the pin that controll this ledstrip work with also 3.3V logic (I don't know if the MK3 work with 5V or 3.3V logic)

Comment: It's 3.3V but now I am thinking, should I have connected the battery to the white charger instead of VIN?